# ORA-00907: Distinct, join and group by in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, linq, entity-framework

I'm getting the error code ORA-00907, when executing the linq query below. It seems to be Oracle specific. The problem seems to be the "group by" subquery.

Lets say I have these two tables: USER and ADDRESS, with columns:
USER{userid, addressid}, 
ADDRESS{addressid, streetname}

Table ADDRESS contains several rows with the same addressid, so I guess I would like to group the ADDRESS-table (DISTINCT) on the addressid so I only get one match with addressid in USER-table, it should also be a LEFT JOIN, so if there is no match I still get the USER-record.

I have tried several different approaches, My code (example):

```
List<MyObject> result =
(
    from u in context.USER.Where(i => i.userid > 100)

    join a in (from address in context.ADDRESS group address by address.addressid)
    on u.addressid equals a.FirstOrDefault().addressid into joinedaddress
    from lfjoinedaddress in joinedaddress.DefaultIfEmpty()

    join email in context.EMAIL on u.userid equals email.userid into jemail
    from lfjemail in jemail.DefaultIfEmpty()

    select new MyObject()
    {
       UserId = u.userid,
       StreetName = lfjoinedaddress.streetname,
       UserEmail = lfjemail.emailaddress
    }
).ToList();
```

Someone know how to achieve this, by rewriting the query so it works against Oracle.

**UPDATE:**

This is the generated sql-query, except the "email":

```
SELECT 
1 AS "C1", 
"Extent1"."USERID" AS "USERID", 
"Extent1"."ADDRESSID" AS "ADDRESSID"
FROM  (SELECT 
      "USER"."USERID" AS "USERID", 
      "USER"."ADDRESSID" AS "ADDRESSIF",       
      FROM "EXT"."USER" "USER") "Extent1"
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT "Distinct1"."ADDRESSID" AS "ADDRESSID1", "Limit1"."ADDRESSID" AS "ADDRESSID2", , "Limit1"."STREETNAME" AS "STREETNAME1"
    FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT 
        "Extent2"."ADDRESSID" AS "ADDRESSID"
        FROM (SELECT 
      "ADDRESS"."ADDRESSID" AS "ADDRESSID", 
      "ADDRESS"."STREETNAME" AS "STREETNAME",       
      FROM "EXT"."ADDRESS" "ADDRESS") "Extent2" ) "Distinct1"
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT "Extent3"."ADDRESSID" AS "ADDRESSID",  "Extent3"."STREETNAME" AS "STREETNAME"
        FROM (SELECT 
      "ADDRESS"."ADDRESSID" AS "ADDRESSID", 
      "ADDRESS"."STREETNAME" AS "STREETNAME",       
      FROM "EXT"."ADDRESS" "ADDRESS") "Extent3"
        WHERE ("Distinct1"."ADDRESSID" = "Extent3"."ADDRESSID") AND (ROWNUM <= (1) ) ) "Limit1"
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT "Extent4"."ADDRESSID" AS "ADDRESSID", , "Extent4"."STREETNAME" AS "STREETNAME"
        FROM (SELECT 
      "ADDRESS"."ADDRESSID" AS "ADDRESSID", 
      "ADDRESS"."STREETNAME" AS "STREETNAME",       
      FROM "EXT"."ADDRESS" "ADDRESS") "Extent4"
        WHERE ("Distinct1"."ADDRESSID" = "Extent4"."ADDRESSID") AND (ROWNUM <= (1) ) ) "Limit2" ) "Apply2" ON ("Extent1"."ADDRESSID" = "Apply2"."ADDRESSID2") OR (("Extent1"."ADDRESSID" IS NULL) AND ("Apply2"."ADDRESSID3" IS NULL))))
```

Comment: Would this be a similar question that might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266128/entity-framework-left-outer-joins-and-group-into-throws-ora-00907-missing-rig?rq=1

Comment: What sql does this generate?

Comment: @Dennis_E: yes that is the same problem. But I cant find a workaround.

Comment: @DanielKelley: The question is now updated with the sql-query

Comment: FirstOrDefault() doesn't guarantee any order and I see no order by statement within the sub-query; therefore, your query is randomly grabbing an address where the addressid matches. Unless this is a simplified example, you have a data modelling issue as well. And once that's fixed, you probably won't even need the offending group by statement anymore.

Comment: @Sybeus: Okay. In my situation, I just need to get one item that matches addressid, I don't care about the order. I'm not the database owner, so I cannot control the way it's modeled. What I want is just "DISTINCT" on ADDRESSID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISTINCT** is applied to tuples not an individual value within a tuple. If *STREETNAME* is always the same per *ADDRESSID* in table *ADDRESS*, then you want **DISTINCT** tuples of (*ADDRESSID*, *STREETNAME*).  Which you could simply do with selecting the distinct columns of `context.ADDRESS` as your subquery and omit the `.FirstOrDefault()`.

```
join a in 
(
    from address in context.ADDRESS
    select new
    {
        address.addressid,
        address.streetname
    }
).Distinct()
on u.addressid equals a.addressid into joinedaddress
from lfjoinedaddress in joinedaddress.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

If *STREETNAME* is not always the same per *ADDRESSID*, then you don't want **DISTINCT** at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In Solution #1, the problem is that I also have other columns that might be different even if ADDRESSID and STREETNAME is always the same (my example seems to be too simplified). Lets say I have two rows where ADDRESSID and STREETNAME have the same values. And in a third column the values are different between the two rows. So unfortunately the .Distinct() doesn't work in this case. When I run the code from Solution #2, I get this exception: The method First can only be used as a final query operation. Consider instead use the method FirstOrDefault in this instance

Comment: Updated answer to explicitly define ADDRESSID and STREETNAME as the distinct tuple. Shouldn't matter about additional columns in table now. I realize now that while my 2nd solution works in some LINQ providers, it will not work with Entity Framework which appears you require; therefore, I have removed the 2nd solution from my answer.